# Elements are not visible for appium desktop on IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I am using Appium desktop, run Appium on emulator. Elements are not visible.

[image]

Comment: Try adding accessibility identifier, that way you could use that identifier for path. it is not best thing to do, but could help you

Comment: You can add accessibility identifier to most of the UI elements.
Try dot the UI elements that you want to have the identifier with `your_element.accessibilityIdentifier`.

Comment: In xcode, open view you want, select third tab and you will see accessibility label